# How to use log4j 2.17.1 in Spring-Boot 1.3.6 with Java-8

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, java-8, log4j

My Java-8 project is build using spring-boot 1.3.6 version, Which by default inherit 'log4j-core-2.4.1', but now I want to upgrade log4j-core to 2.17.1 for which I added
<log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version> into pom.xml file of my project. The build runs fine but the error says:-

```
*ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationSource;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;*
```

Comment: Upgrade your application to a more recent version of spring boot because spring boot 1.X line long EoL.. Strongly recommend to upgrade..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you **can't**.

A breaking change in `log4j-core` (cf. [LOG4J2-1547](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1547)) renders version 2.7.0 and later incompatible with Spring Boot 1.3.x. You can either:

- upgrade to Spring Boot 1.5.x or later,
- downgrade to Log4j 2.3.2 (which includes the newest [security patches](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html)):

  ```xml
  <properties>
      <log4j2.version>2.3.2</log4j2.version>
  </properties>
  ```

Comment: Ok. Now I tried to upgrade to Spring Boot 1.5.x , But its causing errors in a lot of  java classes and functions, like:- findOne(), Delete(), @Valid annotation, and various imports along with error on handleWithAdapter() method inside IntegrationFlow() for file writing. I don't want to change the code. Is there any solution?