# approach to upgrade my log4j1.2.17 used inside springboot-starter-parent 1.5.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2, slf4j

Log4j1.2.17 included inside my code is not used directly, rather it is being called from another JAR file – `log4j-over-slf4j1.7.25`  and this Jar is being used from the `spring-boot-starter-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar`

1. I tried updating the log4J version in below dependency, but looks this `log4j:log4j:jar:2.16.0` does not even exist and I have to look for some other approach.

   ```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <!--<version>1.2.17</version>-->
        <version>2.16.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. I tried removing above dependency, but it also did not work

Answer (score 1):

There is no 2.16.0 version of the `log4j:log4j` artifact. Log4j 2.x introduces breaking architectural changes and a new [`org.apache.logging.log4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j) group id.

The easiest way to switch from Log4j 1.x to Log4j 2.x and at the same time redirect all logging APIs to the Log4j API is to use Spring Boot starters. Just remove the `log4j:log4j` dependency (also as transitive dependency) and add:

```xml
<properties>
  <log4j2.version>2.20.0</log4j2.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

**Remark**: This works from Spring Boot 1.5.x up, older versions of Spring Boot can not upgrade to the latest Log4j 2.x version, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70847022/11748454).

**Edit**: If you have [`org.apache.log4j.Logger`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) in your code, you **are** using Log4j 1.x directly.

The most future-proof solution to this is to migrate to either Log4j 2.x API or SLF4J by following option 2 of the [migration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#option-2-convert-your-application-to-the-log4j-2-api-log4j-api). There is even an [OpenRewrite recipe](https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/logging/log4j/log4j1tolog4j2) for that.

If you don't have time or resources to migrate, you can postpone the migration by adding (together with the **runtime** dependencies above) the Log4j 1.2 to 2.x API bridge as dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You just need to make sure that `log4j:log4j` is **not** bundled with your application or you'll have unexpected conflicts (`log4j-1.2-api` is a **replacement** for `log4j:log4j`).

Comment: HI Piotr, Can you please give an example  on how to  redirect all logging APIs to the Log4j API is to use Spring Boot starters. TIA
My existing loggers are breaking with above POM change.
This approach can work as my springboot version is 1.5.6

Comment: Also, Please comment if u have any idea on "Enabling the Log4j 1.x bridge" from
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html

Comment: @VishalGandotra, to bridge two logging APIs you need to add a specific runtime dependency. The starters contain exactly the dependencies you need to bridge JUL, Log4j API and SLF4J to a common backend. Can you clarify what does "loggers are breaking" mean? What is the full class name of your loggers?

Comment: By loggers I meant the log classes which we have used in code as below, once i made the changes the u mentioned, the code was not able to resolve the import statement "org.apache.log4j.Logger;"
-------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class ClassName extends Thread {
 private Logger log = Logger.getLogger("logName");
-------------------------------------------------------

Comment: So you **are** using Log4j 1.x in your code. I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above issue with replacing the log4j framework with reload4j as below,  and my code passed the vulnerability scan. Hope it may help you

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.reload4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>reload4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, I had to exclude below two dependencies from my code

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```